# How to access hardware keys programmatically in windows phone 'mango'

Tags: windows-phone-7, hardware

I am searching on how we can programmatically access hardware buttons
i.e start,search,back,volume keys,screen lock in windows phone (mango).
Currently I had found that no keys other than 'Back key' which can be controlled programatically in WP.

Thanks
Gaurav

Answer (score 3):

The only other key you can control other than "back", is the camera key which you can do via the [PhotoCamera](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.photocamera%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) APIs.

s

Comment: hi Shahar thanks for your reply. so you mean there is no api available in mango which can check start,search,volume key and screen lock button.

Comment: All other keys aren't accessible to enforce a consistent behaviour for the user (e.g. the user expects to launch the Bing-Search when pressing the Search-Button etc.). Also you can re-map the camera-button, but if it is not a simliar functionality (to take a picture or video in your app) it's most likely that the app won't pass the marketplace certification.

Comment: Hi Anheledir thank you for your reply. I dont want to change the functionality i just want to check whether hardware keys are working properly or not programmatically. i.e want to display a message 'key is working' when we pressed the key. kindly reply.

Comment: Anhelendir's reply stands - the search, start, volume and power buttons are inaccessible in any way. The camera button is accessible - and for your purpose, I think they will allow you to use it, but cannot be sure.